# "Male/female" is to "gender" as "man/woman" is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms, analogy

What is the hypernym for *man* and *woman*? I don't think it is *gender* because that would've been *male* and *female*.

Comment: The *hypernym* is "person", as both men and women are people, but I don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: Species? Mars to Venus?

Comment: You assume that a word can only be a hypernym of one set of things. That is not true. (Just like a word can be a synonym/antonym of many different things, depending on context.) So *gender* is fine, and so is *sex*, for *male/female* and *man/woman* and *bloke/gal* and *stud/mare*.

Comment: LOL I was thinking species as well.

Comment: Is there a more specific word to classify "man" "woman" unambiguously from "male" "female" as you said gender can also apply.

Comment: It very much depends on what you want to use the hypernym *for*. If the grouping does not focus on gender difference, *people, humans, adults* and several other options might be right. If it does, there may not be a true hypernym.

Comment: More like I want a different variable name for a Word template.  Since I am using "gender" for "male/female" already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Man and woman are different *sexes*.

Comment: Man and woman aren't really sexes. Male and female are.

Comment: Not sure if that is so. If you ask someone what sex is A, the answer would be *male* or *female*. Or if you asked *What are the sexes?* or *Name the sexes*, the answer would be the same.

Comment: As much as it bothers me, 'sex' and 'gender' are now, alas, synonyms.

Comment: Not really. _Sex_ defines people by physical characteristics. _Gender_ defines them by mental characteristics.

Comment: Biologically speaking, male and female are sexes. Whether or not they are also genders depends on what level of distinction you are making between biology and orientation. And whether man and woman are sexes or genders or both is another matter altogether.

Comment: Nouns have gender; people have sex.

Comment: @Barrie So theoretically, there can't be a "gay", "lesbian" sex.  Those would be genders right?  Would transexual be a sex or a gender?

Comment: Yes, probably. I fear my experience and expertise in such matters is limited.

Comment: Based on Meriam Webster's definition #2 it seems this is the correct answer.  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sexes

Definition #1 discusses about the "state of" where as definition #2 specifies "group of"

Comment: Also gender http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genders definition #2b states  the behavioral, cultural, or psychological traits typically associated with one sex.  So you can have a male or female mentality.

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano - "gay" or "lesbian" are neither a sex nor a gender, that would be an orientation.  They are all separable characteristics - nothing in a person's sex or their gender specifies who they may or may not be attracted to (slurs about how a 'real [gender] wouldn't want...' being set aside as mere bigotry).  A transsexual would be a person whose sex and gender profoundly disagree with each other, I think, so that term doesn't replace either answer, while the opposite (cissexual) means someone whose categories don't disagree with each other.

Answer (score 4):

Man and woman are gender. Social roles defined by society. There is nothing genetic or biological about wearing high-heels, for example. Men don't do that (usually...) because social norms say they shouldn't.

Male and female, on the other hand, are a biological matter of sex that have nothing to do with social norms. With apologies to Simone de Beauvoir, you are born female but society makes you a woman.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for "gender identity". Male and female are genders, but a person can *identify* as a man or a woman regardless of whether they are physically male or female.

But of course, this is a very fuzzy subject, and if you ask 10 different people you're going to get 15 different answers.

Comment: "Gender identity" makes more sense for a field label.  And it is less ambiguous.  In addition it will make it easier to map to applicable pronouns for messages.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question rather than the title: the hypernym of woman and man would, depending on context, be either human or adult. A hypernym is just a word whose meaning encompasses the meaning of a word or group of words.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, it might be easier (and possibly more correct) to switch the hypernyms in your example.

Male/female makes a bit more sense with "sexes" as the hypernym, since it is talking about physical gender characteristics.  This sort of debate shows up in the comments about Barrie England's answer.  In that case, man/woman would have the hypernym of "gender", since it is a more socially constructed division.

Of course, they are close enough in meaning you might get away with using either interchangeably if you're using them casually - either male/female or man/woman , or else 'sexes' or 'genders'.  But if you want to talk *about* these sets of terms or distinguish between them, the standard usage is that "sexes" go with male/female for denoting the physical, and "genders" go with man/woman for social meaning and construction.

Answer (score 0):

"Male" and "female" refers to the property of belonging to a particular category in a categorization scheme, and/or those categories themselves.  "Man" and "woman" refers to an individual with that property, along with several others, most notably being human and being of a certain age and/or state of maturity.

If you get hypernyms by removing distinctions, then the hypernym is whatever the word is for something possessing all the remaining properties.  "Human", "person", "individual", "adult" and "member of a (two-)gendered species" are all reasonable choices, depending on which categories are relevant in whatever context you want to use such a hypernym.